# Hole-punching Amasty Full Page Cache

Tags: magento-1.8, full-page-cache

We're using Magento 1.8.1.0 and Amasty FPC 1.6.10.
I'm attempting to holepunch a small part of a .phtml template (in this case, it's the defaule page\html\header.phtml template), but I am having trouble finding any instructions on how to do so.

According to [this documentation](https://amasty.com/docs/doku.php?id=magento_1:full_page_cache#how_to_hole_punch_cart_welcome_blocks), there are ways to holepunch custom blocks, blocks w/ ajax, and CMS blocks, but nothing about how to do it when blocks aren't involved.

Any help would be much appreciated.